# Компиляция кода запускаемого на Mac имея Visual Studio Windows

Tags: c#, .net-5

Собрал небольшое консольное приложение. Под Windows компилируется без проблем. При попытке компиляции под OSX-X64 вылетает с ошибкой "не удалось определить причину ошибки". Есть ли возможность с винды собрать консольное приложение, которое можно будет скачать на Mac и свободно запускать? Есть ли вообще на маке возможность запускать сторонние файлы? К сожалению ни одного мака в доступе нету. Собирал под .NET 5.0

Comment: вообще можно, при компиляции под мак, дотнет создаст исполняемый файл в нужном формате, а ваше сообщение об ошибке ничего особо не говорит, может стоит добавить больше деталей, какие команды используете? что у вас в csproj? возможно есть зависимости

Comment: К сожалению ошибка именно так и звучит "не удалось определить причину ошибки", в журнале ошибок "System.AggregateException:не удалось определить причину ошибки". Что у меня должно быть в csproj? К сожалению, я не сильно опытен в написании кода, только обучаюсь, поэтому мне сложно сказать конкретно про команды и csproj. Я просто выбираю вариант компиляции "osx-x64" и пытаюсь собрать. При этом под windows компилируется без проблем. Сам код - простейшее консольное приложение уровня "хело ворлд"

Comment: @AK создал метку, можно пилить [описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-5/info) :)

Comment: `AggregateException` - это комбо-исключение, у него внутри есть `InnerException`, что там внутри?

Comment: Я открываю файл с помощью блокнота. Не вижу InnerException. Только то, что я написал.
System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: При публикации произошла ошибка. Не удалось определить причину ошибки. Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале вывода. 
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
---> (Внутреннее исключение #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: При публикации произошла ошибка. Не удалось определить причину ошибки.

Comment: А чем компилируете? [Этим?](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/mac/)

Comment: Я компилирую из под Windows, стандартный Visual Studio

Comment: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-local-folder?view=vs-2019), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58435008/5045688). Ключевой момент - пункт Edit > Target Runtime.